# How do I cite a screenshot from a paper?

Tags: citations, graphics

There is an image in a paper that I want to use in my master’s thesis. I have the PDF file of this paper and I cant save the image from the file. So I have to take a screen shot. How should I cite the image?

Comment: *I cant save the Image from the file* – unless the paper is profoundly garbled, there are several (free) tools which make this a very easy thing to do, e.g., [PDFImages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdfimages) or Inkscape.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You cite the paper you got the image from in the same way that you cite any other paper. Are you asking how to actually include that image in your thesis? If so, that's a software support question, which is off-topic, here. Try [su] but they'll need full details of what software you're using.

Comment: If you are reusing the image in a document you are writing, don't forget to ask permission to the publisher, who owns the copyright.

Answer (score 16):

You don't cite the screenshot, you cite the paper. If your readers want to look up the source, they don't care how you technically copied the image into your word processor. They want to know where they can find the paper you copied the image from.

Answer (score 2):

It is very much possible and easy to extract the image from the PDF document. 
Please use: http://www.pdfaid.com/ExtractImages.aspx 
or: https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/extract.aspx
or any other tool you can find online by searching for: 'extract images from pdf'.

Please cite the extracted image in APA style (or other applicable style) as follows:

[image]

Figure 2. Male holotye of Hypsiboas gladiator (Kholer et al., 2010, p. 584).

Reference

Kohler, J., Koscinski, D., Padial, J. M., Chaparro, J. C., Handford, P., Lougheed, S. C., & Riva, I. (2010). Systematics of Andean gladiator frogs of the Hypsiboas pulchellus species groug (Annuar, Hylidae). Zoologica Scripta, 39(6), 572-590. doi:10.111/j.1463-6409.2010.00448.x