# Asking authors to send figures from a paper in as separate pdf files

Tags: publications, graphics

In my seminar I have to present a paper which has many nice figures. I use LaTeX and would like to insert some of these figures into my presentation and handout. Ideally, I want these figures to be nice (not screenshots), so I am thinking of writing to authors and ask them to send me the figures they used in pdf format. Is it appropriate request?

Comment: You know that there are various tools to extract figures from a PDF without loss?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, I tried some of them, e.g. `\includegraphics[page=35, viewport=100 450 300 500,clip]{articledocument}`, but it is a pain.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/91649/546)

Comment: I vote no, not appropriate.

Comment: Have you tried right-click-save-image-as (depending on the PDF viewer, I forget what I used but I know several have this feature)? I for one would be a little annoyed to be bothered by some stranger requesting I do such elementary tasks for them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However, all of these methods extract an image as jpeg or png, i.e. image is saved in pixels. This alters the quality. I am looking for a way to get images in vector format (e.g. pdf).

Comment: If this is mathematics, you can get the sourcecode of any arXiv preprint straight from the arXiv. That said, this is a tricky question, and this kind of requests are in a grey zone as far as etiquette is concerned: Some authors are fine with sharing their graphics sources, others are annoyed and think worse of you if you ask. No, it is not academic misconduct.

Answer (score 2):

The question is difficult to answer in the way it is phrased. I would find it hard to believe that there was a seminar activity asking you to find other people's figures and present them. There are lots of immediate copyright issues from doing that.

There is a certain amount you can do based around the fair use rules for academic use and giving acknowledgement to authors. The norm there would just be the screenshot, with the acknowledgement (the latter of which should cover the fact that image will not be of the highest quality).

But it may be that the request for high quality figures is really asking you to create your own, whether this means coming up with something novel, or generating your own (cited) version of the original figure.

In any case, I don't think that contacting the authors is appropriate here.

Comment: Unless it's for a University class or assignment. I'm not sure if OP is talking about a seminar at a conference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am talking about the seminar at university if it is relevant.